# Git Push-to-Deploy - Can't change release type

Tags: google-app-engine

i have a issues with "Git Push-to-Deploy" appengine feature.

I log in https://console.developers.google.com/ go to my application -> Cloud development -> Releases
and try to change "Release type" to "Java: Use maven to build, test, deploy" i got error "Failed to update release type"

[image: Screnshot]